# CORS Chrome wildcard '*' Angular 8?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, cors, signalr, signalr.client

I get the following message CORS only in Chrome, Mozilla works fine:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8002/dataHub/negotiate'
>   from origin 'http://172.16.30.79:4200' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the
>   response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials
>   mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Server returns me these headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with,Vary,Server,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Date
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Vary, Server, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Date
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2019 18:32:09 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

My connection using SignalR is:

```
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
      .withUrl("http://localhost:8002/dataHub")
      .build();

 this.connection
      .start({withCredentials: false})
      .then(() => {
});
```

As you can see server sends one header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

In Mozilla I see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://172.16.30.79:4200`

Why does Chrome replace  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://172.16.30.79:4200` on `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` I dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `Configuration`:

```cs
//Configure CORS policy
services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
  builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://172.16.30.79:4200")
  .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
  .AllowAnyMethod()
  .AllowAnyHeader()
  .AllowCredentials());
});
```

Then on `Configure`:

```cs
//Cors Policy
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```